# how to get strong email validation REGEX

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

I am using **email address validation** in my code and for that I am using a Regex.
Can anyone suggests me a regex which will not accept email addresses eg. abc@def.commmmmm or abc@xyz.com.com.com or abc@gmail.c.

Please help me.

thanks
any information is valuable for me.

Comment: ohh.. I didnt get that while asking a question..!

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP =

```
 /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i,
```

i have used in validation engine as well as custom js file.

Comment: Thanks...! I hope this will omit name@domain.com.com

Comment: Nice, can you explain me which rules it uses ?
 - No two dots after the @
 - No longer extenstion (.com) then .. ?
 - ...
Kind regards

Comment: I have checked for it but it accepts name@domain.com.com..I want which doesnt accepts this

Comment: @lan S : it is email validation of jquery validation engine.

@Akki : sorry i haven't solution email like... `abc@test.com.com` ..!! :(